# Undefined reference while using gcc

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

Trying to compile this code and keep getting "undefined reference to..." compiler errors. I'm not sure what's going on. I was told you don't need to include a reference to a ".c" file as long as you reference its ".h" file.

My terminal command: `gcc Main.c semaphore.o -L. -lst -o test`

```
/tmp/ccGSIjXz.o: In function `main':
HW3.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `init_buffer'
HW3.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `init_buffer'
HW3.c:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `init_buffer'
/tmp/ccGSIjXz.o: In function `Thread1':
HW3.c:(.text+0x159): undefined reference to `c_deposit'
/tmp/ccGSIjXz.o: In function `Thread2':
HW3.c:(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `c_remove'
HW3.c:(.text+0x1b9): undefined reference to `c_deposit'
/tmp/ccGSIjXz.o: In function `Thread3':
HW3.c:(.text+0x1e8): undefined reference to `c_remove'
HW3.c:(.text+0x206): undefined reference to `c_remove'
HW3.c:(.text+0x21a): undefined reference to `c_remove'
HW3.c:(.text+0x238): undefined reference to `c_deposit'
HW3.c:(.text+0x252): undefined reference to `c_deposit'
/tmp/ccGSIjXz.o: In function `Thread4':
HW3.c:(.text+0x28c): undefined reference to `c_remove'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's the code:

Main.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "st.h"
#include "buffer.h"

#define MAX_CHARS 81
#define BUFF_SIZE 12
#define NULL_CHAR
typedef struct {
}ThreadInit;

static buffer *buffer1;
static buffer *buffer2;
static buffer *buffer3;

void *Thread1();
void *Thread2();
void *Thread3();
void *Thread4();

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    buffer1=init_buffer(BUFF_SIZE);
    buffer2=init_buffer(BUFF_SIZE);
    buffer3=init_buffer(BUFF_SIZE);

    ThreadInit thread1={};
    ThreadInit thread2={};
    ThreadInit thread3={};
    ThreadInit thread4={};

    if (st_thread_create(Thread1(), &thread1, 0, 0) == NULL) {
        perror("st_thread_create failed for thread 1");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (st_thread_create(Thread2(), &thread2, 0, 0) == NULL) {
        perror("st_thread_create failed for thread 2");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (st_thread_create(Thread3(), &thread3, 0, 0) == NULL) {
        perror("st_thread_create failed for thread 3");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (st_thread_create(Thread4(), &thread4, 0, 0) == NULL) {
        perror("st_thread_create failed for thread 4");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    return 0;
}
void *Thread1()
{
    int c;
    while (1)
    {
        c=fgetc(stdin);
        c_deposit(buffer1,c);
        if(c==EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    st_thread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}
void *Thread2(void *state)
{
    int c;
    while(1)
    {

        c=c_remove(buffer1);
        if(c==EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
        if(c=='\n')
        {
            c=' ';
        }
        c_deposit(buffer2,c);
    }
    st_thread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;

}
void *Thread3(void *state)
{
    int c;
    while(1)
    {
        c=c_remove(buffer2);
        if(c==EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
        if(c=='*' && c_remove(buffer2)=='*')
        {
            c_remove(buffer2);
            c='^';
            c_deposit(buffer3,c);
        }
        else
        {
            c_deposit(buffer3,c);
        }
    }
    st_thread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}
void *Thread4(void *state)
{
    int counter=0;
    int c;
    char output[MAX_CHARS];
    output[MAX_CHARS-1]='\0';
    while(1)
    {
        c=c_remove(buffer3);
        if(c==EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            output[counter]=c;
            if(counter==80)
            {
                printf("%s",output);
                counter=-1;
                memset(output,'\0',BUFF_SIZE);
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
    st_thread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}
```

Buffer.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "semaphore.h"
#include "buffer.h"

buffer *init_buffer(int size)
{

    buffer *new_Buffer;
    new_Buffer=malloc((sizeof(buffer)));

    createSem(new_Buffer->emptyBuffer, size);
    new_Buffer->emptyBuffer=malloc(sizeof(semaphore));

    createSem(new_Buffer->fullBuffer, 0);
    new_Buffer->fullBuffer=malloc(sizeof(semaphore));

    new_Buffer->chars=malloc(sizeof(char)*size);

    new_Buffer->size=size;

    new_Buffer->nextIn=0;
    new_Buffer->nextOut=0;

    return new_Buffer;
}

void c_deposit(buffer *buffer, char c)
{
    down(buffer->emptyBuffer);
    buffer->chars[buffer->nextIn]=c;
    buffer->nextIn=(buffer->nextIn+1)%buffer->size;
    up(buffer->fullBuffer);
}
int c_remove(buffer *buffer)
{
    int c;
    down(buffer->fullBuffer);
    c=buffer->chars[buffer->nextOut];
    buffer->nextOut=(buffer->nextOut+1)%buffer->size;
    up(buffer->emptyBuffer);
    return c;
}
```

buffer.h:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "semaphore.h"

typedef struct{
    semaphore emptyBuffer;
    semaphore fullBuffer;
    int nextIn;
    int nextOut;
    int size;
    char *chars;
}buffer;

void c_deposit(buffer *buffer, char c);
int c_remove(buffer *buffer);
buffer *init_buffer(int size);
```

Comment: it is a linker error. did you forget to add `buffer.c` to list of files?

Comment: Please post your `Makefile` or gcc command line.

Comment: Just added it, realized that might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
gcc Main.c semaphore.o -L. -lst -o test
```

To

```
gcc Main.c semaphore.o buffer.c -L. -lst -o test
```

Comment: it says no such file or directory

Comment: Okay that worked, but I'm getting some crazy errors now for that as well, should I just post another question?

Comment: @sreya, spend sometime and try to figure them out for yourself. If you can't, yeah, I guess post another question. Try to trim the problem down to the smallest example that shows the error.

Answer (score 0):

> I was told you don't need to include a reference to a ".c" file as long as you reference its ".h" file.

This is incorrect. Every `.c` source file needs to be compiled to a `.o` object file. The object files are then linked together to form the final binary. You can let gcc do this for you by simply specifying all of your `.c` files on your gcc command line.

The only thing `#include "buffer.h"` does, is copy the contents of that `.h` file into the current `.c` file. You do this so the `.c` file knows about all of the types referenced, and the prototypes of the functions you'll be calling, (so it can generate the correct code for the call).

In this case, you simple need to add `buffer.c` to your gcc command line.

Comment: when I say reference I meant like, `#include "buffer.h"` and `#include "buffer.c"`

Comment: **NEVER** `#include "xxx.c"`

Comment: okay, that's what I meant in the sentence you highlighted originally

Answer (score 0):

try

```
gcc Main.c buffer.c semaphore.o -L. -lst -o test
```

you might want to add a prototype for `init_buffer` to `buffer.h`:

```
buffer *init_buffer(int size);
```

Comment: I actually did, bad copy/paste